# iOS swift Codable not working with Alamofire for JSON nested data?

Tags: ios, swift, alamofire, codable

I am new to Alamofire and Codable concept In iOS can someone tell me how to use this to access my json data.

This is my json response.

```
{"subscriptions": [
        {
            "batch_user_id": 23,
            "batch_name": "demo batch",
            "course_name": "IELTS",
            "start_date": "Nov 01 2019",
            "end_date": "Nov 30 2019",
            "no_of_days": 21,
            "total_no_of_days": 30,
            "extended_date": "Nov 30 2019",
            "extended": false,
            "course_extensions": [
                {
                    "id": 31,
                    "amount": "3500.0",
                    "course_id": 1,
                    "is_active": true,
                    "number_of_days": 5
                },
```

this is codable code:

```
 struct course_extensions: Codable {
        let id: String
        let amount: String
        let course_id: String

        private enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
            case id = "id"
            case amount = "amount"
            case course_id = "course_id"
        }
    }

    struct subscriptions: Codable {
        let batch_user_id: String
        let batch_name: String
        let course_extensions: course_extensions

        private enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
            case batch_user_id
            case batch_name
            case course_extensions = "course_extensions"
        }
    }
    struct User: Codable {
        let status: String
        let message: String
        let subscriptions: subscriptions
    }
```

This is my service call with alamofire:

```
// MARK: - Service call

func fetchUserData() {
    AF.request(SMAConstants.my_subscriptions, method: .get, parameters: nil, headers: nil)
        .responseJSON { (response) in
            switch response.result {
            case .success(let value):
                let swiftyJsonVar = JSON(value)
                print(swiftyJsonVar)
            case .failure(let error):
                print(error)

            }
    }
}
```

Can some one help me out access nested array data with codable . thanks in advance.

Comment: add complete json response

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You’re missing the structure for that outermost portion of the JSON:

```
struct ResponseObject: Codable {
    let subscriptions: [Subscription]
}
```

And, you can use normal camelCase properties:

```
struct Subscription: Codable {
    let batchUserId: Int
    let batchName: String
    let courseExtensions: [CourseExtension]
}

struct CourseExtension: Codable {
    let id: Int
    let amount: String
    let courseId: Int
    let isActive: Bool
}
```

A few observations:

- The `struct` type names should begin with uppercase letters as a matter of convention.
- Those `CodingKeys` are not necessary in this case.
- Be careful on your types. A number of these are `Int` and `Bool`. Only use  `String` types if the value is in quotation marks.
- Obviously, I’ve excluded a few properties from the above `struct` types for the sake of brevity, but add any missing properties, but sticking with the camelCase convention.

Anyway, you can then tell the decoder to convert snake_case JSON keys to camelCase property names using:

```
do {
    let decoder = JSONDecoder()
    decoder.keyDecodingStrategy = .convertFromSnakeCase

    let object = try decoder.decode(ResponseObject.self, from: data)
    print(object.subscriptions)
} catch {
    print(error)
}
```

So, for example, if using Alamofire 5:

```
let decoder: JSONDecoder = {
    let decoder = JSONDecoder()
    decoder.keyDecodingStrategy = .convertFromSnakeCase
    return decoder
}()

func fetchUserData() {
    AF.request(SMAConstants.mySubscriptions))
        .responseDecodable(of: ResponseObject.self, decoder: decoder) { response in
            guard let value = response.value else {
                print(response.error ?? "Unknown error")
                return
            }

            print(value.subscriptions)
    }
}
```

That produced:

```
[Subscription(batchUserId: 23, batchName: "demo batch", courseExtensions: [CourseExtension(id: 31, amount: "3500.0", courseId: 1, isActive: true)])]
```

---

By the way, I notice that your dates are in the format of `MMM d yyyy`. Would you like to convert those to `Date` objects? If so, you can use a decoder that specifies a date formatter like so:

```
let decoder: JSONDecoder = {
    let decoder = JSONDecoder()

    decoder.keyDecodingStrategy = .convertFromSnakeCase

    let formatter = DateFormatter()
    formatter.locale = Locale(identifier: "en_US_POSIX")
    formatter.dateFormat = "MMM d yyyy"
    decoder.dateDecodingStrategy = .formatted(formatter)

    return decoder
}()
```

Then you can define `startDate` and `endDate` to be `Date` objects. Then when you present these dates in the UI, you can use a `DateFormatter` to show a nice localized rendition of the date, rather than just the fixed, ugly `MMM d yyyy` format.

To present a date in the UI, you’d then do something like:

```
let dateFormatter: DateFormatter = {
    let formatter = DateFormatter()
    formatter.dateStyle = .medium
    return formatter
}()
```

And then:

```
label.text = dateFormatter.string(from: date)
```

And a English speaker in the US will see:

> Apr 15, 2019

A US-based Spanish speaker will see:

> abr. 15, 2019

A Spanish speaker in Spain will see:

> 15 abr 2019

Bottom line, the user will see dates in the format that they expect them, rather than being hardcoded in some specific US English format. And you also have the choice to use `.long` format where space allows (e.g. “April 15, 2019”) or `.short` where you’re really tight for space (e.g. “04/15/19”). Just pick the `dateStyle` that suits your particular needs.

Comment: @ Rob  nice explanation point by point thanks for your time..

Comment: How to assign this data to tableview labels.

Comment: "amount" how to get value for this key and where should I call  tableview.reload()

Comment: how to assign in table..  for example:            let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: cellIdentifier, for: indexPath as IndexPath) as! SMAIeltsTableViewCell
        
     cell.titleLbl.text = (subscriptions.first?.courseExtensions.first?.amount ?? "Not found")

Comment: I have to show  course extensions in my tableview.  only one course_extensions we have  in the api.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/202092/discussion-between-rob-and-john-js).

Comment: Thanks for your time and effort for clear expression. Thank you so much its working like champ.. But in table label value is showing like this  “”  optional(“3500.0”). “” how to show only 3500.0

Comment: That’s unrelated to the question at hand. I’ve put my comment in the chat.